# Compare column to vector in R

Tags: r

I want to compare every row in a column in a dataframe to a single vector.

```
temp_df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 2, 1),
                      y = c(4, 4, 2))

> temp_df
  x y
1 3 4
2 2 4
3 1 2
```

I want to compare each `y` to every single `x` to see if `y` is greater than all of the `x` values. If the `y` is not greater than all `x` values then I want to return `FALSE`.

I can achieve this by looping through my dataframe but I want to avoid that. This is the result I am seeking:

```
> temp_df
  x y     z
1 3 4  TRUE
2 2 4  TRUE
3 1 2 FALSE
```

I am trying to do this is base R but am open to other solutions also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
temp_df$z <- sapply(temp_df$y, function(u) all(u > temp_df$x))
temp_df$z
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```